# string cannot be find using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I have following text in a file.

```
BEGIN
   BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
   BEGIN
       BEGIN
           VALUE "CompanyName", "MyCompany"
           VALUE "FileDescription", "MyFile"
           VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
           VALUE "InternalName", "Something.exe"
           VALUE "LegalCopyright", "MyCopyright "
           VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Something.exe"
           VALUE "ProductName", "MyProduct"
           VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.0"
       END
   END
END
```

I need to replace the line with FileVersion with some other string. To find that line I am using following regex, but its not able to find it.

```
"(^\s*VALUE\s*`"FileVersion`",\s*)`"[0-9]+,\s*[0-9]+,\s*[0-9]+,\s*[0-9]+`"$"
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

PS: Not sure if it matters but the complete script is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209311/how-to-get-teamcity-build-version-into-unmanaged-dlls-and-ocx-controls) that I am trying to use.

Comment: You are trying to match commas, but the version number contains dots. Replace `,`s between digit patterns with `\.`s.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Wiktor, you need to replace the commas with periods in your RegEx. This should work:

```
"(^\s*VALUE\s*`"FileVersion`",\s*)`"[0-9]+\.\s*[0-9]+\.\s*[0-9]+\.\s*[0-9]+`"$"
```

Or to simplify that whole section of the script (using look behinds and look aheads, as well as option groups to combine FileVersion and ProductVersion matching into one match) this should work as well:

```
(Get-Content $file) -replace '(?<=^\s*"(FileVersion|ProductVersion)",\s*")\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?=")', $rc_version -replace '(?<=^\s*VALUE\s*"(FileVersion|ProductVersion)",\s*")\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?=")', $rc_version_spaced | Set-Content $file
```

Answer (score 1):

That *script* does some substitutions on the target before it gets to the regex.

To match the Version line, use something like this:

```
(?mi)^[ \t]*value[ \t]+"fileversion"[ \t]*,[ \t]*"([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*)"[ \t]*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/a8cJ4n/1

More info

```
 (?mi)                              # Inline modifiers; multi-line, case insensitive
 ^                                  # BOL
 [ \t]* value [ \t]+                # VALUE
 "fileversion" [ \t]* , [ \t]*      # FILEVERSION
 " 
 (                                  # (1 start), Version numbers
      [0-9]+ 
      (?: \. [0-9]+ )*
 )                                  # (1 end)
 "
 [ \t]* 
 $                                  # EOL
```